# How to avoid [Vue warn] for custom directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js

I created a custom directive and it's working good, but when I run the mocha test for the component where I use this custom directive I receive this warning message `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: scroll-text`, tell me please how to fix that

test file:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import { scrollText } from "z-common/services"
import ZSourcesList from "./ZSourcesList"

Vue.use(scrollText)

const stubs = [
    "z-text-field",
    "v-progress-circular",
    "v-icon",
    "z-btn"
]

describe("ZSourcesList.vue", () => {
    const sources = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sources.push({
            field: "source",
            // format numbers to get 2 diggit number with leading zero 1 -> 01
            value: `cluster-${i.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false })}`,
            __typename: "SuggestV2Result"
        })
    }

    it("displays 'No matching sources found' if there are no sources", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(ZSourcesList, {
            mocks: {
                $apollo: {
                    queries: {
                        suggestions: {
                            loading: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            stubs,
            sync: false,
            data() {
                return {
                    suggestions: [],
                }
            },
        })

        expect(wrapper.find(".notification .z-note")).to.exist
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your custom directive on a local vue instance and then mounting to that local vue instance.

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils" 
import { scrollText } from "z-common/services"
import ZSourcesList from "./ZSourcesList"

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(scrollText) // Register the plugin to local vue

const stubs = [
    "z-text-field",
    "v-progress-circular",
    "v-icon",
    "z-btn"
]

describe("ZSourcesList.vue", () => {
    const sources = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sources.push({
            field: "source",
            // format numbers to get 2 diggit number with leading zero 1 -> 01
            value: `cluster-${i.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false })}`,
            __typename: "SuggestV2Result"
        })
    }

    it("displays 'No matching sources found' if there are no sources", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(ZSourcesList, {
            mocks: {
                $apollo: {
                    queries: {
                        suggestions: {
                            loading: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            localVue, // Mount this component to localVue
            stubs,
            sync: false,
            data() {
                return {
                    suggestions: [],
                }
            },
        })

        expect(wrapper.find(".notification .z-note")).to.exist
    })
})
```

Using a local vue instance instead of the global in test cases will also prevent polluting the global vue instance and help to prevent side effects in other test cases.

Comment: I get the same warn message, only if I put in directive property  the imported directive value to wrapper options then I'll avoid warn message

Comment: What is `scrollText`? Is it a plugin that registers a plugin or just a directive? If it's just a directive then instead of registering using `localVue.use(scrollText)` you'll need to register it as `localVue.directive('scrollText', scrollText)`